# Is there a word for permanent solution?

Tags: synonyms

I would prefer a positive connotation.

Comment: One you should probably avoid is "final solution".

Comment: nothing about the term **'solution'** implies a temporary nature or a negative connotation.

Comment: Yes: *Death.* Lest it be thought to have a negative connotation, consider the [Wandering Jew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wandering_Jew), the [Flying Dutchman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flying_Dutchman_%28opera%29), and the [last line of Plato's *Apology](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0170%3Atext%3DApol.%3Apage%3D42);* also [Socrates' last words in the *Phaedo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0170%3Atext%3DPhaedo%3Apage%3D118),* since the cock sacrifice to Asklepios was thanksgiving for cure (of ALL ills!).

Answer (score 15):

A term that *implies* a permanent solution is:

> ***A resolution***

Comment: Could you include a definition with a reference that substantiates your claim here?  To me, a *resolution* is more like a statement of intent, that may or may not actually be carried out. A *solution* is a *fix*- it solves a problem, whereas a *resolution* is only a vow to take some action.

Comment: A problem is _resolved_ when not only is there a solution, but also when that solution is applied. This is not the same usage of _resolve_ as, for example, used when discussing the UN or a determined person.

Comment: @Jim OED> "IV. Solving, answering, formal declaration, and related senses.
 14. 
 a. 




  
 (a) The action or an act of finding the answer to a question, the solution to a problem, etc.; the elimination or easing of doubt. Also: the fact of such an answer, solution, etc., having been found."

Comment: @Araucaria I kind of feel the same way Jim does. Of course it implies a solution has been applied, but it does not really express permanence of the solution at all.

Comment: @rschwieb Do you mean Jim or Inductiveload?

Comment: @Araucaria Oh, yeah, looks like I wrote the wrong name :)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, *solution*. Anything else is a stop-gap, or a patch, or a *temporary* solution. The word *solution* only needs to be qualified to specify when it is *not* a permanent one. If it is, you just call it a *solution*.

Take, for example, [this definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solution) from Merriam Webster (emphasis mine):

> so·lu·tion
>
> : something that is used or done to deal with **and end a problem** : something that **solves a problem**
>
> : the act of solving something
>
> : a **correct answer** to a problem, puzzle, etc.

There is nothing that implies that a solution is not permanent. Quite the contrary, a solution is always permanent unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 4):

A permanent solution is said to be *[definitive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/definitive)*:

> serving to supply a final answer, solution, or evaluation and to end
>   an unsettled unresolved condition

Answer (score 2):

*panacea* can have this connotation. Although it really means a solution to all ills, in practice, it tends to mean a comprehensive solution to a problem, e.g. "A panacea for our IT problems".

Comment: In real life, whatever is touted as a panacea never is, meaning you'll need to find another solution later, which means in practice it is not permanent.

Comment: It's true that the term is sometimes used ironically, but it's not exclusively used that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard this phrased used in comp. sci and programming.

Canonical Solution

Comment: Canonical refers to "most correct" and may not be "most permanent" however.

Answer (score 0):

You could go Latin, it sends the message better.
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/immutabilis#Latin

Answer (score 0):

In the mathematics, science and other disciplines, a permanent solution is a "proof"

Comment: Hmm. A *proof* substantiates a *theory*. I don't think it's necessarily the same as a *solution*, which is in response to a *problem*.